# Printing formatted nested lists with strings and integers in each sublist

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting, nested-lists

```
list = [["John Doe", 40], ["Jane Doe", 38],["Joe Bloggs", 34]]
```

I've got a nested list similar to the above, with each sublist containing a string and an integer. When hitting print within my for loop I get the ugly, unformatted output;

```
for item in list:
print(item)
```

I'd like to tidy it up a bit (i.e. remove brackets and quotations) but can't get my head around how I'd do it. Can someone help me out?

Comment: You can add literally one character for somewhat prettier output: `print(*item)`.

Answer (score 4):

Try the `*`, sometimes called the "splat" operator, which unpacks the list for you.

```
items = [["John Doe", 40], ["Jane Doe", 38],["Joe Bloggs", 34]]

for item in items:
    print(*item)

# OUTPUT
# John Doe 40
# Jane Doe 38
# Joe Bloggs 34
```

Answer (score 0):

You are working with a multidimensional list.

This code works for a one dimension list:

```
for item in list:
    print(item)
```

You can retrieve any element in a list using a number, using the position in the list of the element. The number 0 is for first element, The number 1 for second element in the list and so on.

So with:

```
list = [["John Doe", 40], ["Jane Doe", 38],["Joe Bloggs", 34]]
list[0]
```

You retrieve the first list inside the original list:

```
["John Doe", 40]
```

So with the code:

```
list = [["John Doe", 40], ["Jane Doe", 38],["Joe Bloggs", 34]]
list[0][0]
```

You retrieve the name inside the first embeded list:

```
"John Doe"
```

And with the code:

```
list = [["John Doe", 40], ["Jane Doe", 38],["Joe Bloggs", 34]]
list[0][1]
```

You retrieve the age in the embeded list:

```
"40"
```

You can make a iteration in a multidimensional list refering each element by its position in the list:

```
list = [["John Doe", 40], ["Jane Doe", 38],["Joe Bloggs", 34]]

for elemento in list:
    print("Name: " + str(elemento[0]))
    print("Age: " + str(elemento[1]))
    print(" - - -  - - -  - - -  - - -  - - -  - - -  - - - ")
```

Comment: Perfect thank you. Made working with these lists a lot more sense.